# Mapping enum and string

Tags: c, arrays, string, enums

I have an array say `arr[3]` and I used enums to index into the array say

```
typedef enum {
ABC,
DEF,
XYZ
}INDEX;
```

I store values in the array as `ar[ABC] = 100` and so on...
Now I have a file having the strings as `xyZ = 2, dEF = 3, abc = 4`. I parse this file and check for the string. If the string is `xyZ` then I need to store the value in the array `arr[XYZ]` and so on.. I am struck in mapping the string with enums.How will I know the enum index with the strings in file. Any ideas please. Hope I am clear.Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately in C there is no built in coercion of a string to an enum. You need to do this yourself. A hash table (as H2CO3 says) is a good way. Or if the number of enum values is small, use `if` statements and `stricmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take `'a'` as index `0`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    ABC,
    DEF,
    GHI,
    JKL,
    MNO,
    PQR,
    STU,
    VWX,
    YZ,
    N
} INDEX;

#define GET_INDEX(x) (((x) - 'a') / 3)

int main(void)
{
    char *s[] = {"abc", "def", "mno", "def"};
    int i, arr[N] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arr[GET_INDEX(s[i][0])] += 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("arr[%d]=%d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea with enums? Apart from the hashtable as suggested by other experts. Can I have a `char *s[] = { "abc","def","xyz"};` and use its index as enum index? I think it will take more space for more elements in the `s[]`.

Comment: You can't **stringize** an enum, you need a hash function (and take care of collisions), I have edited my answer for use enum, its very fast and takes 'a' as index 0